# Primeng - How to add a button inside the header of a multi-select/dropdown?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I would like to add a button somewhere inside the header of the multiselect component so user can click that button instead of relying on the onChange event of the [multiselect](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) component.

On the documentation, there are only a couple of pre-defined directive.

`pTemplate="selectedItems"` and `pTemplate="item"` to edit the template. How to i add custom html aside from those two. I would like to add the button besides the search input form?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the p-footer or p-header component to include buttons in the header or int the footer of a p-multiSelect element. The p-footer and p-header components are a part of the PrimeNG library that allows you to add custom content.

Here is an example of how you can use the p-footer component to include buttons in the footer of a p-multiSelect element:

```
<p-multiSelect
  [options]="options"
  optionLabel="name"
>
  <p-footer>
    <div class="flex justify-content-between p-1">
      <button pButton pRipple type="button" label="Save" icon="pi pi-save" class="p-button-outlined p-button-sm"></button>
      <button pButton pRipple type="button" label="Reset" icon="pi pi-refresh"
              class="p-button-outlined p-button-sm"></button>
    </div>
  </p-footer>
</p-multiSelect>
```

you can check this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-lh5wy9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot override the component's Html, however you can play a workaround, copy [**these files**](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/src/app/components/multiselect) in your project, change their html so it will suits you and then **change your imports from the *`primeng dependency`* to that *`customized component`***.

Comment: it seems like there's no other way then, i think i'll just send them a feature request so they can allow for a more flexible template customization. btw, Thanks for your answer